# CakePHP: how to customize the default error view

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I know you can over-ride individual error views by adding the corresponding files into View/Errors/ but instead of creating a dozen files for each error (error400.ctp, error500.ctp, etc) I'd rather just have one generic error view. Currently, if I haven't created a file for the specific error thrown, I see the generic cakePHP error page and I suspect that is coming from somewhere in the core. Is it possible to customize this default view and keep the error views much more DRY?

Answer (score 0):

By default app/Layouts/default.ctp is used for error messages. You can customise this by adding a new layout and pointing each of error400.ctp and error500.ctp to it by using

```
$this->layout = 'my_error';
```

See [Exceptions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html)

Comment: You're proposing we just bypass the views all together? Will the error messages and other variables be available automatically there?

Comment: Yeh that's what I am proposing, if that fits your needs. I believe everything should then be available to you automatically.